# Passing an array of arrays into lodash intersection

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, lodash

I have an array of arrays that contain objects:

```
let data = [[{a:0}, {b:1}], [{a:1}, {b:1}]]
```

Now I would want to make a [lodash intersection](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#intersection) of these two arrays, returning `[{b:1}]`

When I do this:

```
import {intersection} from 'lodash'

return intersection([{a:0}, {b:1}], [{a:1}, {b:1}])
```

the result is correct.

But when I do

```
return intersection(data)
```

I just get the same result back.

Is there an easy way to pass all the arrays from data to the intersection function? My initial thought was to use .map, but this returns another array...

Comment: I don't think you'll get anything back from this because I believe it is comparing references, not values. You should use [`intersectionBy`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#intersectionBy) or [`intersectionWith`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#intersectionWith) instead.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could just [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) the array.

```
intersection(...arrayOfarrays);
```

Or, in a pre ES6 environment, use [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply):

```
intersection.apply(null, arrayOfArrays);
```

Or, you could convert `intersect` into a function with spread-out arguments:

```
const intersectionArrayOfArrays = _.spread(_.intersection);
intersectionArrayOfArrays(arrayOfArrays);
```

---

Be aware though that intersection in lodash [doesn't automatically work on arrays of objects](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/issues/926).

You could use [intersectionBy](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#intersectionBy), if you want to intersect on the property `b`:

```js
const arrayOfArrays = [[{a:0}, {b:1}], [{a:1}, {b:1}]];
console.log(
  _.intersectionBy(...arrayOfArrays, 'b')
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

or [intersectionWith](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#intersectionWith), if you want to intersect on the same objects by reference or deep comparison:

```js
const a1 = {a: 0};
const a2 = {a: 1};
const b = {b: 1};
const arrayOfArrays = [[a1, b], [a2, b]];

// reference comparison
console.log(
  _.intersectionWith(...arrayOfArrays, (a, b) => a === b)
)

// deep equality comparison
console.log(
  _.intersectionWith(...arrayOfArrays, _.isEqual)
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @MihaŠušteršič glad to help drugar :)

Comment: @nem035 Thank you for adding the correct uses of object array intersection. I will nitpick, however, and point out that in your `intersectionWith` section, you say that `_.isEqual` compares the objects by reference, which is not true. `_.isEqual` does a deep object property value comparison.

Comment: @mhodges you're absolutely right, thanks for pointing this out. Fixed.

Comment: Hello, thank you @nem035 for your answer: it really made my day.

Comment: I tried `_.intersection(...myArrayOfArrays)` and got `[ts] Argument of type '{}' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ArrayLike<{}>'.
       Property 'length' is missing in type '{}'.`

Comment: Anyone who got the same error I got, make sure you cast your myArrayOfArrays object like this: `myArrayOfArrays: any[]`

Comment: Janac's solution above works but for those that do not use `any` in their codebase, you can cast your array to `myArrayOfArrays: YourArrayType[][]`